# Connect AS400 from PERL

Tags: database, perl, ibm-midrange

I want to connect to AS400 using Perl. The DBI module is not supporting it. Can you suggest any other module? What other stuffs do I need? I am working on a Linux environment.

Comment: AS/400 _was_ a systems platform från IBM, now called "IBM System i". I suspect you need to start by figuring out what service it is you want to connect to. There are many databases that can run on an i-series server.

Comment: Which Database you need to connect? Is it DB2?

Comment: @CalleDybedahl it hasn't been named System i since 2008 when the hardware was unified with the System p hardware. The hardware is now called Power Systems or Pure Systems, and can run IBM i, AIX, or Linux. IBM i is the OS formerly known as i5/OS or OS/400. The current naming scheme is subject to change at any time by IBM's marketing department.

Comment: @CalleDybedahl IBM i primarily runs DB2 for i.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21297335

Answer (score 0):

In the past, in absence of dedicated driver, I interfaced Perl with AS400 via standard services like rexec and ftp.

```
# warn: this use clean user/passwd. Use with care
$param="call pgm(someLib/someProc) parm('someUsefulParameters')";
system("rexec -a -l asUser -p asPaswd as400ipAddress \"${param}\" 2>/dev/null >myOutput.txt");
# ...then read myOutput.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Perl, but if there is a driver that can access via JDBC or ODBC, you should be able to connect fine with that.